# Retrieve & Display 'Person or Group' type column in a List using SPFX

Tags: spfx-webparts, list-item, person

I am trying to Get data from a Custom List & show it as a table using SPFX.
By Refering this [**Link**](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/retrieve-sharepoint-list-items-using-sharepoint-framework-development-model/),  displayed `Single line of text` type columns. 
But when trying to display `Person or Group`, particular column values are *undefined*  in table in the Webpart.
I tried to change the column type from `string` to `object` in the ListModel, but no change in the result.

```
export interface ISPList {
  USERNAME: string;
  EMAIL: string;
  COUNTRY: string;
  USERROLE:Object;  //People and Groups type column
}
```

How can I retrieve & display `Person or Group,Lookup` these type of columns.
Thank you

**Edit**

By referring [ashik](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/a/243732/58747) answer, now my listmodel look like this,

```
export interface ISPList {
  USERNAME: string;
  EMAIL: string;
  COUNTRY: string;
  USERROLE:{
    Title:string
  }
}
```

and `_renderList` function is,

```
 private _renderList(items: ISPList[]): void {
    debugger;
    let html: string = '<table class="TFtable" border=1 width=100% style="border-collapse: collapse;">';
    html += `<th>UserName</th><th>Email</th><th>Country</th><th>UserRole Title</th>`;
    items.forEach((item: ISPList) => {
      html += `  
           <tr>  
          <td>${item.USERNAME}</td>  
          <td>${item.EMAIL}</td>  
          <td>${item.COUNTRY}</td>
          <td>${item.USERROLE[0].Title}</td> 
          </tr>  
          `;
    });
    html += `</table>`;
    const listContainer: Element = this.domElement.querySelector('#spListContainer');
    listContainer.innerHTML = html;
  }
```

But, how can I add 'Person or Group' field to my `_getMockListData` function which is like below,

```
  private _getMockListData(): Promise<ISPLists> {
    return MockHttpClient.get(this.context.pageContext.web.absoluteUrl).then(() => {
      const listData: ISPLists = {
        value:
          [
            { USERNAME: 'abc', EMAIL: 'abc@xyz.com', COUNTRY: 'IND' },
            { USERNAME: 'cdy', EMAIL: 'cdy@xyz.com', COUNTRY: 'IG' },
            { USERNAME: 'pqr', EMAIL: 'pqr@xyz.com', COUNTRY: 'IND' }
          ]
      };
      return listData;
    }) as Promise<ISPLists>;
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the rest api url you should mention the people field in expand section

Eg:

```
private getPeopleFieldValues() : any {  
    return this.context.spHttpClient
      .get(`${this.context.pageContext.web.absoluteUrl}/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('ListName')/items?$select=*,PeopleFieldName/Title,PeopleFieldName/EMail&$expand=PeopleFieldName`},
      SPHttpClient.configurations.v1)
      .then((response: SPHttpClientResponse)=>{                   
          return response.json();
      });
  }
```

Now place the output in the console.log and find the path required to show the names of the people field values.

Hope it helps.

Comment: one question I have `_getMockListData` function to represent data in local workbench. How to represent 'Person or Group' column there.

Comment: Please refer the below link:
https://github.com/SharePoint/sp-dev-fx-webparts/blob/master/samples/js-display-list/src/webparts/jsDisplayList/JsDisplayListWebPart.ts

Comment: Did it work? Was the link helpful?

Comment: Sorry, I was busy with another work. The above link, they are only displaying title field. I am checking the samples. Thanks any way